# Can we read a tableau extract using java in earlier versions of tableau?

Tags: java, tableau-api

I have a tableau extract "extract.tde" from which i want to read data and insert into some other database like sql server, Is it possible to do so?

Comment: This question needs more detail. Extract is in what format? What database? Is there a JDBC driver for that database?

Comment: please check the edited question, yes i have jdbc driver for database @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 10.3, the Tableau SDK allows you to create and append data to Tableau Data Extracts, but not read from them. The advent of their Hyper database technology may eventually change that - but they haven't announced that to my knowledge.

So currently, you can read from an extract using Tableau Desktop and manually export the data as a CSV, or if you have Tableau Server, you can cobble together a way to convert it to CSV from a script by publishing the data source, wrapping it in a simple viz, and using curl to fetch the data behind the viz by placing ".csv" at the end of the URL.

It's probably a lot simpler to have whatever process creates the extract also export the data in the form you want.

I think of extracts as cached (usually temporary) copies of a query, similar to a materialized view. They aren't really intended to be a data source of record.